# JavaScript alert to another page when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

I need to get my JavaScript code from a green button that when clicked by mouse it goes to another page by the alert function, needs to be a local file, not a random website! Here is the snippet of my code where it needs to go, just need help on how to re-write!

```
//Add event listener to canvas element
    canvas.addEventListener('click', unction(event) {
      //Control that click event occurred within position of button
      //NOTE: This assumes canvas is positioned at top left corner 
      if (
        event.x > buttonX && 
        event.x < buttonX + buttonW &&
        event.y > buttonY && 
        event.y < buttonY + buttonH
      ) {
        //Executes if button was clicked!
        alert('Button was clicked!');
  }
```

Comment: Hi Tom, it is not clear what you are asking for (e.g. the alert function doesn't redirect which makes the question a bit confusing) and also it would be good if you could add more detail about the local file (is it a local file on your computer? on the server? on the user's computer?). Read [ask] and complete the [tour] for more information (and to win your first badge).

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I need the button to open a new window, yes a local file, just another html page in the same folder!

Comment: I still don't fully understand what you are looking for, maybe [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) to open a different page on the same window, or [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to open a page on a different window/tab?